# Completely Removing Mac OSX from MBP

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have a 2009 MBP that runs Linux Arch and OSX on a dual boot. I have no use for OSX on this machine. I installed it 12 months ago, and straight after installation I set up Arch via BootCamp and have never logged into OSX.

It's using 20GB of my HDD space doing nothing. When I installed from BootCamp and partitioned I remember that BootCamp reserved 20GB space of OSX and wouldn't let me go beyond that.

Is it possible to totally remove OSX and just have Arch running on this MBP? I don't mind reinstalling Arch again as everything I need on Arch is all backed up anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Piece of cake, boot the Mac in target mode, connect it to a computer and repartition / erase the drive. You also can remove drives from portables easily and connect tem to an inexpensive ($5) USB to sata adapter and format things.